# how to give an alert if specific number is not written in input field on clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, alert

I have an input field and I want the user to put in a number that is predetermined, like 500, if the user clicks the submit button and value they typed in is NOT 500, there should be a javascript alert. If the user does type in 500 and then clicks the submit button then alert should not happen.

```
<input name="number" type="text" size="36" maxlength="60" />
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="submit"  />
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: So follow any tutorial on validation

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use ids instead of a form with submit because you will have to reload the page everytime and read the GET parameters out of the URL.

Use onclick instead, like this example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                if (document.getElementById("number").value != "500")
                    alert("Your alertmessage");
            }
        </script>
    </head><body>
        <input id="number" type="text" size="36" maxlength="60" />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `onclick` handler rather than a submit handler for your submit button and assign an `id` to your `input`. The onclick function will evaluate your input's value. You can parse the input value to make it an integer and check it against 500.

Or, you can ignore the `parseInt` part and compare the value to "500". Whichever you prefer.

If the value passes the conditional, then pass that value to your submit functionality.

```js
const checkNum = () => {
  if (parseInt(document.getElementById('thisNum').value) !== 500) {
    alert("NOT NUMBER")
  } else {
    submitFunction(document.getElementById('thisNum').value)
  }
}

const submitFunction = (x) => {
  console.log(x)
  //your submit functionaliy
}
```

```html
<input id="thisNum" name="number" type="text" size="36" maxlength="60" />
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="checkNum()" />
```